# Sql select statement to find double booking in a certain time period

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have to do some analysis on a table these columns: 
`Id, UserName, DateFrom, DateTo`. I have to find out a User has more the one entry for
the same time period. I´m wondering if there is a way to do this in a single Select statement?..... Otherwise I cannot think of anything better then a stored procedure... Can someone help me
out with some ideas and hints.

```
Id----------UserId-------------DateFrom------------DateTo
1-----------Tim123-------------------- 11/19/2012 08:00---11/19/2012 11:00
2-----------Tim123-------------------- 11/19/2012 10:00---11/19/2012 11:00
3-----------Tim123-------------------- 11/19/2012 12:00---11/19/2012 17:00
1-----------John123--------------------11/19/2012 08:00---11/19/2012 11:00
```

Comment: Please show sample data and what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sqlite> insert into user_data values(1, "john", "12-nov-12", "25-nov-12");
sqlite> insert into user_data values(2, "john", "24-nov-12", "25-dec-12");
sqlite> insert into user_data values(3, "jack", "12-nov-12", "25-nov-12");
sqlite> insert into user_data values(4, "jack", "26-nov-12", "30-nov-12");

sqlite> select distinct ud1.userid 
        from user_data ud1, user_data ud2
        where ud1.userid = ud2.userid 
              and ud1.datefrom <= ud2.dateto and ud2.datefrom <= ud1.dateto
              and ud1.id < ud2.id;
john
```

The idea is that

- if period A starts before the end of period B
- and period A ends after the start of period B

then there is overlap.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 
    on t1.UserName = t2.username
    and t1.DateFrom <= t2.DateTo -- this is how to check for any overlap
    and t1.DateTo >= t2.DateFrom -- this is how to check for any overlap
    and t1.id < t2.id -- don't join to self, which would otherwise match
```

Comment: Say you have the ranges `(1 Jan, 3 Jan)` and `(2 Jan, 4 Jan)`. They'll go through the comparison twice, once as `t1, t2` and once the other way round. In neither case will `t1.DateFrom >= t2.DateTo`, although the ranges clearly overlap. I'm sure it's just a backwards comparisons somewhere, though.

Comment: This cannot work since as soon as one of the `DateFrom` is **after** another `DateTo` (first check), the only conclusion is that there are no overlaps between the two joined entries.

Comment: @Laurence fixed by simply changing `!=` to `<`

Comment: @jvivenot you're actually wrong. get out a pencil and paper and work through the edge cases. you'll see that this is the correct way to find overlapping dates. I challenge you to show me some data that doesn't give the correct comparison result using my logic

Comment: The data I supplied still breaks this. Neither `1 Jan or 2 Jan are >= 3 Jan or 4 Jan`, so `t1.DateFrom >= t2.DateTo` isn't true, which ever range gets mapped to `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: @Laurence ah... ok i got the directions flipped - fixed

Answer (score -1):

You can use a nested query, and COUNT to keep track of number of occurrences

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.UserName, t1.DateFrom, t1.DateTo
 FROM your_table_name t1
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM your_table_name t2 
 WHERE t1.DateFrom=t2.DateFrom 
 AND t1.DateTo = t2.DateTo)>1
```

Comment: That seems to count equal time periods rather than overlapping ones, though maybe that's what the OP is after. The question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: I thought that was what he was after. I'm not sure, you might be right.